# create-react-app Typescript 3.5, Path Alias

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I am trying to setup Path alias in my project by adding these values to tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@store/*": ["store/*"]
    },
```

And if I create an import, neither IntelliJ or VSCode bother me:

```
import { AppState } from '@store/index';
```

But when I compile the application I get this warning:

```
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)
```

And it bombs saying it cannot find the reference:

```
TypeScript error in C:/xyz.tsx(2,26):
Cannot find module '/store'.  TS2307
```

Is there any workaround or it is not supported by `create-react-app --typescript`?

Comment: do you using custom webpack?

Comment: Yes, I do use react-app-rewired to customize webpacks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` in `package.json` and configure next:

### **react-app-rewired**

```js
// config-overrides.js
const {aliasWebpack, aliasJest} = require('react-app-alias')

const options = {} // default is empty for most cases

module.exports = aliasWebpack(options)
module.exports.jest = aliasJest(options)
```

### craco

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

### all

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```

Comment: react-app-rewire-alias also requires you to modify the npm scripts in package.json. Here is my code example if anyone interested: https://github.com/GW-Web-Enterprise/ReactJS/commit/c15eb084596ea8c7c258529ba9117bc88f3071b8. This code example removes the baseUrl compiler option and still keeps back the relative import for files at the src/* root to prevent any confusion might have such as import routes from 'src/routes' instead of import routes from './routes'. Because 'src' might make you think there is an external NPM package named 'src'

Comment: It compiles but it does not resolve in vscode

Comment: Seems *"Not resolve in vscode"* is not related to react-app-rewire-alias or creact-react-app etc. Check what is [(ts/js)config.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782883/2969544) - may be something wrong with it or vscode options.

Answer (score 54):

In my case ,i solved this issue using [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco) and [craco-alias](https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias)

1. Install [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco) and [craco-alias](https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias)
   : `npm install @craco/craco --save && npm i -D craco-alias`
2. Create `tsconfig.paths.json` in root directory

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "baseUrl": "./src",
           "paths": {
              "@components/*" : ["./components/*"]
            }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend `tsconfig.paths.json` in `tsconfig.json`

   ```
   {
       "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
       //default configs...
   }
   ```
4. Create `craco.config.js` in root direcory

   ```
     const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

     module.exports = {
        plugins: [
          {
             plugin: CracoAlias,
             options: {
                source: "tsconfig",
                // baseUrl SHOULD be specified
                // plugin does not take it from tsconfig
                baseUrl: "./src",
                /* tsConfigPath should point to the file where "baseUrl" and "paths" 
                are specified*/
                tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.paths.json"
             }
          }
       ]
     };
   ```
5. in `package.json` swap `"start": "react-scripts start"` with `"start": "craco start"`

Comment: And then you should be able to use e.g: `import Bla from '@components/Bla';`? Where I have created a file at `./components/Bla.tsx`.

Comment: I turned your steps into a script: https://pastebin.com/KkPUjZBU with the addition of my above comment. Unfortunately it fails with `Can't resolve '@components/Bla'`. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: did you create components dir in src directory? If not , you need change absolute path in configs `"baseUrl": "./src"`

Comment: or 61 line `cat > components/Bla.tsx` change on `cat > src/components/Bla.tsx`

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. Yes, I am trying to have a components package outside of src. I will try editing `"baseUrl"`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. If this does not work for anyone, please triple check your baseUrl and paths.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you need to replace the other scripts, like `"build": "craco build"`, etc?

Comment: Only this answer's solution works for me in 2022

Comment: I'm trying to follow [Atomic Design by Brad Frost](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). To do that I was setting paths in `tsconfig.paths.json` and extending it in the `tsconfig.json`. But then too I was getting the Module not found error. Upon searching I came here and it seems the last piece of puzzle was `craco-alias` since I'm using craco in my React App. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

## Path aliases no longer work in tsconfig.json

**you can do this instead**, to directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add base URL to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

then you can directly import stuff from the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

Comment: The problem here is that VS Code highlight the import line as an error as it isn't able to make the connection.

Comment: This one solve relative path problem, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Edit - 20/3/20 - Above answer has a solution with a plugin.**

Had the same problem. At the time of posting it is currently not supported as is.

This feature is still in development with the CRA team:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6116

If you edit the tsconfig CRA removes changes: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6269

There are some hacks in this thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118 to get aliases working however require customization to the CRA setup which isn't suitable for my use case (using CRA as is).

Answer (score 4):

@oklas. I've resolved using the following in config-overrides.js which is the same as above. But Thanks a lot for sharing this answer:

```js
const { alias, configPaths } = require("react-app-rewire-alias");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  alias({
    ...configPaths("base-tsconfig.json"),
  })(config);
  return config;
};
```

Comment: Thanks this working only need add base-tsconfig.json path! testing with React 16.13.1

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but i've found an extremly simple solution using only package.json features.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@yourAlias": "file:./path/to/your/folder"
}
```

It works both in node.js and webpack projects

Comment: At least it seems working :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you did this? It does not seem to work for me!

Comment: @Thijmen from tests i did, this is working fine with node.js using require, and webpack using import. This is not working fine with node.js using import. Is this your case ?

Comment: I eventually managed to get it working as illustrated in the comment by @Иван Яковлев!

Comment: For cra with typescript, works togehter the `paths` option in `tsconfig`, tho those "packages" are also under `src`.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is just naming a folder inside `./src` `@` and setting the `baseURL` in the `tsconfig.json` to `src`.

Imports will then have a leading `@/` like `import { MyComponent } from "@/components/MyComponent";` or `import { TodoEndpoint } from "@/endpoints/TodoEndpoint";`. Since there is no library named `@` in NPM this will not lead to conflict with other `node_modules` imports.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

folder structure

```
+src
| +@
| | + components
| | +-  MyComponent.tsx
| | + endpoints
| | +-  TodoEndpoint.ts
| index.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Have also solved the solution using [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) with `ts-loader` - described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63545611/10813908

The stated setup essentially allows CRA to be extended upon by overidding the build-in webpack config via craco and also allows CRA code to directly reference typescript files in the external/shared packages in your mono-repo.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 for those who works with the [ejected](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) TypeScript create-react-app you can set aliases via webpack in `config/webpack.config.js` with the following:

```js
    // ... the other keys of webpack config;
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // ... here set your aliases among ones the CRA sets itself
            // NB: __dirname will refer to ./config so you have to put '../src' to move up from ./config folder and set @src tp ./src, not ./config/src;
            '@src': path.join(__dirname, '../src')
            // Here set your other aliases if needed.
        }
    }
```

Then use the alias in your ts/tsx files like this:

```js
import logo from '@src/assets/logo.svg';
```

Here is [webpack resolve docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) for basics.

Note, that the only alias CRA sets itself is `src`, so you can use `import logo from 'src/assets/logo.svg';` with no changes to webpack config. If the alias works in non-ejected app you have to check yourself.