# compilerOptions.paths must not be set (alias imports are not supported)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I'm trying to map paths in tsconfig.json to get rid of **relative paths** hell. My **React App is based on Create-React-App**.
I tried this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281741/how-to-use-paths-in-tsconfig-json) and added paths in my tsconfig.json. My tsconfig.json is as

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

when I compile my project in VS Code, it removes the paths entry from tsconfig.json with the following message. Why alias imports are not supported in my **react-scripts** based React Project?

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: What's wrong with using relative paths?

Comment: If you ever use this feature in Angular, you won't ask this question :)

Comment: @RB19  Here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778994/14487032

Comment: Why React is so problematic, I am coming from Angular and trying to switch to React, have problems with almost everything, including simple ts import paths

Comment: I can understand your pain.... Same here. I also have an Angular background but I think it's a tradeoff between flexibility and features. Angular has first class support for Typescript but it's not the case with React. Still I think you will enjoy React once go through this initial transition period :)

Answer (score 12):

**Path aliases are no longer supported**

you can do this now, to directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `jsconfig.json` file add base URL to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

then you can directly import stuff from the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```

Comment: Where does the information come from that Path aliases are no longer supported? I have not found anything spontaneously.

Comment: On React start up.
`- compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)`
But there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347253/11127541)

Comment: Welp: `Error: Your project's 'baseUrl' can only be set to 'src' or 'node_modules'. Create React App does not support other values at this time.`

Comment: For some reason this is the only way to make it work, my guts feeling is that react-script has different versions.

Answer (score 6):

I made to [Angelo P's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68332470/11127541) answer work by changing the `config-overrides.js` to

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.resolve = {
    ...config.resolve,
    alias: {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      "@api": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/API/"),
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
      "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"),
      "@containers": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/containers/"),
      "@css": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/css/"),
      "@customHooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/CustomHooks/"),
      "@helperFuncs": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/HelperFuncs/"),
      "@hoc": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/hoc/"),
      "@middlewares": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/middlewares/"),
      "@models": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/models/"),
      "@store": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store/"),
      "@actions": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store/actions"),
      "@reducers": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store/reducers/"),
      "@sagas": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store/sagas/"),
      "@typings": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/Typings/"),
      "@utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils/")
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.d.ts']
  };
  return config;
};
```

Works like a charm, but the only thing missing is VSCode autocompletion. React starts up with this warning:

```
 The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)
```

So I'm assuming it removes the `path` field from the tsconfig.json and VSCode cannot pick up the aliases, so `ESLint` and `TS` give the following errors in VSCode, but everything works fine.

```
Unable to resolve path to module '@typings/...'.eslintimport/no-unresolved

Cannot find module '@typings/...' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Anyone has a solution for this?

**UPDATE**

Managed to get it all working by making these changes:

`tsconfig.paths.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@api/*": ["./src/API/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@containers/*": ["./src/containers/*"],
      "@css/*": ["./src/css/*"],
      "@customHooks/*": ["./src/CustomHooks/*"],
      "@helperFuncs/*": ["./src/HelperFuncs/*"],
      "@hoc/*": ["./src/hoc/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["./src/middlewares/*"],
      "@models/*": ["./src/models/*"],
      "@store/*": ["./src/store/*"],
      "@actions/*": ["./src/store/actions*"],
      "@reducers/*": ["./src/store/reducers/*"],
      "@sagas/*": ["./src/store/sagas/*"],
      "@typings/*": ["./src/Typings/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `*` at the end of `@.../*`

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

`npm i -D eslint-plugin-import @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    ...,
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".d.ts"]
        },
        "typescript": {}
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you've probably already figured this one out but here's a solution while we wait for a [pull request that adds this to tsconfig](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10014)
Currently having the same issue with create-react-app react v 17.0.2,

I've had a similar issue with gatsby applications where you're not able to just set up alias imports without changing the web pack config

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067555/how-to-make-an-import-shortcut-alias-in-create-react-app) has a good explanation on alias imports within cra *without* typescript, but it should lead to the same configuration at the end of the day.

you'd have to either [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject)(don't do this unless you have other issues you need to solve inside of your webpack config.) or use another package like [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) or [React-App-Rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to configure your aliases through webpack.

[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60598134) is most likely what you're looking for.

install [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) then create config-overrides.js and place this code in there ->

```
//config-overrides.js
const { alias, configPaths } = require('react-app-rewire-alias');

module.exports = function override(config) {
  return alias(configPaths('./tsconfig.paths.json'))(config);
};
```

create your paths object inside of tsconfig.paths.json

```
//tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["components"],
      "@styles": ["styles"],
      "@config": ["config"]
    }
  }
}
```

then extend these options inside of tsconfig (not inside compilerOptions)

```
//tsconfig.js

 "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
```

finally, replace each react-scripts script in your package.json with react-app-rewired

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
},
```

You should be all set to go after this.
Hoping this helps anyone else who runs into this problem with create-react-app.

Comment: Funnily enough, after testing this for a while and finally posting this it broke for me, so if anyone tries this out please do let me know if it works for them.

Comment: Hey! this did work for me! But I had to change the config-overrides.js. Checkout my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347253/11127541).

Comment: Oh sick, Thanks a ton 

Answer (score 4):

In the end, i figured out this is not the issue of `tsconfig`. Instead different build system reads this file and operate a bit differently. For instance, a NextJS build does most of the stuff according to the doc, but a Create React App build actually does not follow this exactly. For instance, I can only make the following work.

```
  import Avatar from 'src/components/Avatar'
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
```

But nothing else with `react-scripts`. I hope this helps a bit in this crazy world.

Comment: And were you able to make the `paths` work only with `react-scripts`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `"baseUrl": ".",` to you compiler options and than you can use the import `src/your/path` directly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `craco` for fixing the problem like that anymore. I've solved this issue by moving the `baseUrl` to the main `tsconfig.json` file like below:

tsconfig:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

tsconfig.path.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "api/*": ["api/*"],
            "assets/*": ["assets/*"],
            "config/*": ["config/*"],
            "components/*": ["components/*"],
            "hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
            "pages/*": ["pages/*"],
            "store/*": ["store/*"],
            "constant/*": ["constant/*"],
            "types/*": ["types/*"],
            "utils/*": ["utils/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Works with react-scripts 5.0 and does not require any additional plugins (craco, react-app-rewired etc). Thank you!

Comment: This does not actually work... it still strips out the `paths`... Here is what it prints out as it gets build...
"The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)"

Comment: @codenamezero, please check the order and exact paths, for example, start the wildcard on the end of the path.