# tsconfig alias path's getting removed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I try to use aliases for my project.
After starting the app the `paths` object gets removed and no alias is working.
This is my current simple `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

After starting it looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My console shows this error message:
[image]

I also tried to move the paths to `tsconfig.paths.json` and extend the `tsconfig.json`.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}

// tsconfig.paths.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@styles/*": ["./styles/*"],
            "@components/*": ["./components/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

My third attemnt was to use `craco` which also doesn't worked out.

**UPDATE**
restarting VSC and the server did the trick for me.
I get it to work with [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file).

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778994/3083470) (and the error message) path aliases are no longer supported. You can try to check out the linked workaround.

Comment: yes i already read about this so i tried it with craco but it still doesn't work. I will try it again.